# Why is Mounting methods not working in reactjs.net when I write on JSX

Tags: asp.net, reactjs, reactjs.net

I'm a noob and I'm trying to compile a JSX following this tutorial :

http://xabikos.com/2015/03/18/Using-Reactjs-net-in-Web-Forms/

using reactjs.net

I'm trying to define a class like this...

```
class First extends React.createClass {

  render(){
  }

  constructor(props) {
  }

  componentDidMount() {
  }

}
```

Render method seems to work fine, but `componentDidMount` is not called, 
and the constructor is also never called, any idea why is this happening?

Comment: -->createClass() has been deprecated since React 16, so it doesn't exist, so use `class First extends React.Component {...}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Are mixing The concept of function based components and class-based components, You can not use `createClass` while using class-based Components, That's why you are not getting what you desire.
The right way to make a component using class is this:-

```
import React from 'react';

class First extends React.Component{
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

    }
    componentDidMount() {

    }
    render(){

    }
}
```

And When You have to make components Using plain functions You have to use this:-

```
var First = React.createClass({
  render:function(){
    //Your view
   }
})
```

I Hope it will solve your problem